# enable to set the input value inside dropdown of datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Below is my code its working cool but i want like in input of datepicker it display January 2016 but inside dropdown of datepicker it display Nov 2016 as selected i want to display same as input field

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<div class="fleft">
       <form method="post">

           <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="date-picker" name="month" id="autoclose" placeholder="filter by month" value="<?=$this->session->userdata('months_day_filter')?>" />

        </form>
        </div>

    <table>
        <thead>

            <th>Name</th>           
            <th>Absent</th>
            <th>Leave</th>

            <th>Days</th>
        </thead>
        <? foreach ($users as $user){ ?>
                <tr class="">
                    <td><?=$user['f_name'] .' '. $user['l_name'] ?></td>
                    <td ><?=$user['absents']?></td>             
                    <td ><?=$user['leave_count']?></td>         
                    <td ><?=$user['working_days']?></td>                

                </tr>   
             <? } ?>

        </tbody>

    </table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'MM yy',
    //defaultDate: null,
    defaultDate: <?=date('y-m')?>,
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
         var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
        //alert(this.value);
     $('.month_form').submit();
    }

  });
});
</script>
    <style>
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none;
    }
</style>
```

please help me to set the input value inside dropdown of datepicker

Comment: can you please give the whole code with html .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the last function code with the following.

```
$(function() {
var fullmonth_array = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
                  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'MM yy',
    //defaultDate: null,
    defaultDate: "<?=date('y-m')?>",
 monthNamesShort : fullmonth_array,
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst){
         var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
        //alert(this.value);
     $('.month_form').submit();
    }

  });
});
```

With this do not need to keep the done button so you can remove it by removing showButtonPanel or set false.

Answer (score 1):

Its done relace your code with following. or add      monthNamesShort : fullmonth_array

```
$(function() {
var fullmonth_array = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
                  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'MM yy',
    //defaultDate: null,
    defaultDate: "<?=date('y-m')?>",
 monthNamesShort : fullmonth_array,
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
         var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
        //alert(this.value);
     $('.month_form').submit();
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: As i select April 2016 from date picker then enter Done button 
my input field is displaying April 2016  but on dropdown it was November 2016 is their any way both will display same value if yes then how? or not then ok it was great thankew for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your *defaultDate* should be in the same format as *dateFormat*. At least this is what the documentation states (http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate). So the line should be

```
defaultDate: <?= date('F Y') ?>,
```

or maybe even better

```
defaultDate: new Date(<?= date('Y') ?>, <?= date('m') ?>, 1),
```